# Forward pan/pinch gesture to mkmapview

Tags: uiview, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController with a MKMapView and an other View (lets say PaintView) on top of the mapView.

When a user touches the PaintView with a pinch gesture, the mapview underneath should respond (as well as the paintView self).
When a user touches the Paintview with a pan gesture the mapview must not respond. (the pan gesture is used for painting).

Is there any possibility to forward the pinch gesture to the mapView?

```
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
[self.view addSubview:self.paintView];


UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
[self.paintView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
panRecognizer.delegate=self;

UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)];
[self.paintView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
pinchGesture.delegate=self;


-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //do sth in the paintView
}


-(void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //forward pinch gesture to mapview
    //do sth in paintview
}
```

Comment: I think this post answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485669/how-to-enable-touchevents-scroll-and-pan-in-mkmapview-below-a-custom-uiview?rq=1